# Intercepting network requests using undetected-chromedriver and seleniumwire - Certificate Error

Tags: undetected-chromedriver, seleniumwire

I am trying to intercept network requests using undetected-chromedriver and seleniumwire in Python. Below are my two attempts:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

class SeleniumDriver(object):
    def __init__(
        self,
        driver_path='C:\\Users\\ranja\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data',
    ):

        self.driver_path = driver_path
        chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()

        self.driver = uc.Chrome(
            executable_path=self.driver_path,
            options=chrome_options
        )

        self.driver.get('https://google.com')
        self.start_intercepting_requests()

    def start_intercepting_requests(self):
        requests = self.driver.requests
        print(requests)
```

> I am getting the error: "AttributeError: 'Chrome' object has no
> attribute 'requests'."

**Attempt 2:
**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver as uc


class SeleniumDriver(object):
    def __init__(
        self,
        driver_path='C:\\Users\\ranja\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data',
    ):

        self.driver_path = driver_path
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

        self.driver = uc.Chrome(
            executable_path=self.driver_path,
            chrome_options=chrome_options
        )

        self.driver.get('https://google.com')
       

        self.start_intercepting_requests()

    def start_intercepting_requests(self):
        requests = self.driver.requests
        print(requests)
```

> In Attempt 2, I am encountering a "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"
> error. I understand that this is related to SSL certificates, but I'm
> unsure how to resolve it while still intercepting network requests.
> Any guidance on how to properly intercept network requests with
> undetected-chromedriver and seleniumwire, considering the SSL
> certificate issue, would be appreciated.